# Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line <i>48</i>

Tags: php, android

In my Android App. I'm trying to authenticate the user, for that I have written a php script to establish connection to the database but unfortunately I'm getting the following error--

***"Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line *48*"***

To resolve this error I have declared ***"$con"*** as global variable but still getting the same error-

My ***db_connect.php*** code is---

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT 
{

    private $con;    

    // constructor
    function __construct() 
    {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() 
    {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() 
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database             
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE); 
        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

   /*       
    * Function to close db connection
    */
    function close() 
    {
    // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($con);

    }   
}

?>
```

Please Help. Thank you..!

Comment: You need to refer to `$this->con`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT 
{

    private $con;    

    // constructor
    function __construct() 
    {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() 
    {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() 
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database             
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($this->con, DB_DATABASE); 

        // returing connection cursor
        return $this->con;
    }

    /*       
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() 
    {
        // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($this->con);
    }   
}

?>
```

Use `$this->con`, instead of `$con`, as `$con` is a class variable, and you are using as a local variable.

Comment: As You suggested I used this->con even I copied your answer but still not working..!

Comment: @Namo, please try again with the above code as I forgot to return `$this->con`, instead I was returning `$con`. If still not work, please mention, if you are getting the same error as `Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line 48`

Answer (score 0):

Problem - `$con` variable in function `connect()` is not assigning value of `$con` to the public variable you have given, and similarly, in `close()` function it was not referencing to the public variable.

Change your function connect as -

```
function connect() 
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database             
    $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE); 
        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }
```

and function close() as -

```
function close() 
    {
    // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($this->con);

    }
```

Final Code -

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT 
{

    private $con;    

    // constructor
    function __construct() 
    {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() 
    {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() 
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database             
    $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE); 
        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

   /*       
    * Function to close db connection
    */
    function close() 
    {
    // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($this->con);

    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: As You suggested I used this->con even I copied your answer but still not working..!